# Syntax for passing list of parameters for dataflow job with gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

After updating my cloud sdk to the latest version today, I could not run my dataflow jobs properly anymore. Up until now I always started them with:

`gcloud dataflow jobs run job_name --gcs-location gs://template_location --parameters from_date="2019-03-01",to_date="2019-04-30"`

But after the update this call resulted in one parameter `from_date` being passed and containing the value `2019-03-01 to_date=2019-04-30` (all together).

I tried passing the parameter list in square brackets, but that causes an immediate error.

So, what's the right way to pass a list of parameters now?

Comment: Could you please specify the new and the old version?

Comment: Now I have

- Google Cloud SDK 322.0.0
- bq 2.0.64
- core 2021.01.05
- gsutil 4.57

Unfortunately I do not know how to find out what the old version was. Also I am using Powershell on Win10

Answer (score 0):

You can try following options to pass all parameters over your script

```
PROJECT='YOUR_PROJECT'
BUCKET='YOUR_BUCKET'

def run():
    argv = [
          '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
          '--job_name=YOUR_JOB_NAME',
          '--save_main_session',
          '--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
          '--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
          '--region=us-central1',
          '--runner=DataflowRunner'
          '--from_date=2019-03-01'
          '--to_date=2019-04-30'
    ]
```

Comment: That does defeat the point of having a parametrization from the CLI though . For now I have resigned to starting the jobs via the Dataflow GUI.